BottomNavigationBar fixes with adjust pan, but changing the layout margin based on Keyboard bounces
I have a problem, I have a navigation tab bar, a map as fragment, and a slide view like in google maps that will show search location and a recyclerview with locations. Only a part of slide view must be shown and after sliding it, it will show the locations. The problem is that when i focus the edit text the keyboard opens and the bottombar goes above the keyboard.
To fix this issue i usen the adjust pan on my activity. The next problem is when i use the adjust pan, now the recycler view with locations stays behind the keyboard. So for this problem i used a keyboard observer, when the keyboard opens it must add some margin the view for it to go up. Since the adjust pan is on acitivy, when i click the layout to go up with locations, it jumps/ bounces because first it will look for adjust pan, and than it will realise that the keyboard is open and change the margin, so it will make a little bounce. How to fix this issue. For the slider i used a library:
implementation ("com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0")
Here is the code that i use to change the margin after i check if the keyboard is open with keyboard observer:
  private fun checkKeyboard() {
        // Calculate the target margin for the CardView when keyboard is open
        val targetMargin = if (isKeyboardOpen) (keyBoardHeight / 1.25).toInt() else 0
        val currentMargin = (binding.myCardView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).bottomMargin

        // Only animate if the margin has changed
        if (currentMargin != targetMargin) {
            val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(currentMargin, targetMargin)
            animator.duration = 300
            animator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
                val params = binding.myCardView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
                // Set only the bottom margin to adjust the position of the CardView
                params.setMargins(params.leftMargin, params.topMargin, params.rightMargin, animation.animatedValue as Int)
                binding.myCardView.layoutParams = params
            }
            animator.start()
        }
    }

    override fun onKeyboardHeightChanged(height: Int, orientation: Int) {
        if (height != previousHeight) {
            previousHeight = height
            isKeyboardOpen = height != 0
            keyBoardHeight = height
              checkKeyboard()
        }
    }

Since i have a map fragment, i cannot use a scrollview, i cannot find a proper solution by days.
